# OSX composer increase memory limit

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I am having memory issues with composer; trying to increase the available amount above 128MO. I have been following the guidelines from [composer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors) but nothing seems to work.

If I `locate php.ini` on my machine I get:

```
/Applications/MAMP_2018-08-02_14-10-44/conf/php7.1.6/php.ini
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
/private/etc/php.ini.default
/private/etc/php.ini.default-previous
```

I `sudo /private/etc/php.ini.default` and change `MEMORY_LIMIT = 512MO`

but when I do `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` I still get 128 MO

now I try `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar` but I get `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

`locate composer.phar` returns nothing....

What am I missing please ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To run composer with no memory limit, first find out where your composer binary is with `which composer`. Use the resulting path like so:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require etc/etc
```

You could also alias this: `alias composer="php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer"`, which would allow you to call composer as you would normally.

Add that line to your bash profile if you want to use composer without limits permanently.

Answer (score 0):

To have no memory limit, set this directive to -1

`php -d memory_limit=-1` which composer `install`